# Permalink structure depending on custom field

Tags: custom-field, permalinks

I'm trying to create a permalink structure that is only used when a certain custom field is filled in.

For instance, when the custom field value of 'premium' is '1', I want to add /premium/ to my permalink structure.

This is my current code:

```
function premium_custom_meta_permalink( $link, $post ){

    $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'premium', true );

    if($post_meta == 1){
       $post_meta = 'premium';  
       $link = str_replace( '%premium%', $post_meta, $link );
    } else {
       $link = str_replace( '/%premium%', '', $link );
    }

return $link;

}

add_filter( 'post_link', 'premium_custom_meta_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

This works up to the point of visiting the post. It then displays an 404-error. What am I doing wrong?

Hoping for help!

Comment: you're generating the link, but you haven't done anything to let WordPress know what to do when those links are requested, you need rewrite rules for that.

Comment: Thank you Milo. Could you help me in the right direction as to achieving this?

Comment: I've added this now: `add_rewrite_rule( 'premium/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?p=1', 'top' );` and `add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?p=1', 'top' );`. This now works (don't know if its best practice) but how will it get the required post id as well?